# How to get rows from the same table with duplicated values in a field_1 and unique values in field_2

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with information about product inventory.

To simplify, let's ignore all fields in the table except two, Product_Code and Colour:

```
Product_Code | Colour
------------------------
1            | Green
1            | Red
1            | Yellow
1            | Green
2            | Black
3            | White
3            | Green
```

I only want to select duplicated products with distinct colours as below:

```
Product_Code | Colour
-------------------------
3            | White
3            | Green
```

The reasons for ignoring Product_Code #1 and #2 are:

1. Produc_Code #1 has duplicated values in colours(Green); and
2. Product_Code #2 is not duplicated in the dataset (only one row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product_Code, Colour
FROM mytable 
WHERE Product_Code IN 
(
   SELECT Product_Code
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY Product_Code
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
          COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT Colour)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single grouped query using the having clause to filter out singular pairs.

```
select Product_Code, Colour
from Products
group by Product_Code, Colour
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: This will be a valid answer for a different scenario such as getting rows where both Product_Code and Colour are both duplicated.